# Export discontinuous range of pages to PDF

Tags: vba, ms-word, export-to-pdf

I am trying to save a Word template in .pdf format. I need to print the following range (1-3,18). The problem is that using "ExportAsFixedFormat2" does not allow me to select that range or at least I dont know how:

```
wdapp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat2 OutputFileName:=savenamepdf, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, Range:=wdExportFromTo, From:=1, To:=3
```

If I use "printout" I can select the range and create the pdf file, but when I try to open it I get an error message like it is broken or corrupted:

```
 wdapp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut OutputFileName:=savenamepdf,_ Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Copies:=1, Pages:="1-3,18"
```

Anyone knows how to print that range?

here is the whole code block

```
Select Case cell
   Case 100
      With wdApp                    
        .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2Filename:=savenameword,ReadOnlyRecommended:=False           
        .ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat2OutputFileName:=savenamepdf,ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF,Range:=wdExportFromTo, From:=1, To:=4
        .ActiveDocument.Close
      End With

   Case 189
      With wdApp
        .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 savenameword
        .ActiveDocument.PrintOut OutputFileName:=savenamepdf,Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Copies:=1, Pages:="1-3,18"
        .ActiveDocument.Close
      End With
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not supported. The only way around it would be to bring together the content into a different/new document, then save that to PDF.

Or, a copy of the document can be opened in Word, the material that's no wanted deleted, then save the document as PDF.

The `PrintOut` method to a file generates a text file that can later be sent to the printer. It's in a special format and the Word content is in a binary format. It's not a converter to other file formats, even if you append a `pdf` extension to the file name, the content won't be PDF.

For more information about what printing to a file is used for:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/what-does-print-to-file-mean/2e73491c-634f-4067-8b7e-c158f647129d

https://word.tips.net/T000462_Printing_to_a_File.html

http://ask-leo.com/what_is_print_to_file_used_for.html

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar issues.
Before calling PrintOut set the wdApp.ActivePrinter to "Microsoft Print to PDF".

```
wdApp.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
```

If your default/application printer is some other printer (even cutepdf or 7-pdf, etc) the resulting pdf is likely to be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same, and couldn't find a way based on word alone.

What I do now is to save the whole document to a pdf file, then extract the pages I need with pdftk. Of course you mast have pdftk installed.

It can be automated in a VBA macro, thus:

```
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:="tempfile.pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
        Range:=wdExportFromTo, From:=page1, To:=99999, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
        IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
        DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=True
        
        With ActiveWindow.View
         .MarkupMode = wdInLineRevisions
         .RevisionsFilter.Markup = wdRevisionsMarkupAll
         .RevisionsFilter.View = wdRevisionsViewFinal
        End With
    commandstring = "pdftk tempfile.pdf cat " & pagerange & " output outfile.pdf"
    StatusBar = commandstring
    
    SynchronousShell (commandstring)
    Kill "tempfile.pdf"
```

the variable "pagerange" contains the desired page range following pdftk conventions.
"Item" can be set to 'wdExportDocumentWithMarkup' if you want. ( I often need to do that )

The code works for me but may not be suitable for production. For one thing, it does not check contention on the temporary file.